# Select Child ByClassName Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have many divs like the following rendering on the same page:

```
<div class="contentUser">
    <div class="innerContent">
        Some data
    </div>

    <div class="contentButtonWrap">
        Some buttons
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to trigger a style change on "contentButtonWrap" when "contentUser is clicked".

I don't know how I can select a child element of a certain class name. Notice that the number of elements that can be rendered within "contentUser" changes from div(contentUser) to div. But there is all ways only one "contentButtonWrap" element within "ContentUser".

This is what I have:

```
function avoidHover() {
    var userDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('contentUser');
    [].forEach.call(userDivs, function(e){
        e.click = function(){

            var target = e.getElementsByClassName('contentButtonWrap');
            target[0].style.backgroundColor='green';
            };
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you consider using jQuery, that would be very easy with it

Comment: No I want the solution to be pure javascript

Comment: I suppose you wanted to use `e.onclick`? Btw, better name that variable `el`, as `e` is typically used for events.

Comment: What exactly does not work about the use of `getElementsByClassName` in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Well don't really care. The problem is that I need to attach an onclick event to all the ContentUser divs just because they don't respond to :hover(css) on ipad(fine on iphone though).

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/sdatavp4/, I would use `addEventListener` though ?

Comment: There is no `e.click`

Comment: I am not able to target the child element . No error is raised so I don't know what I am targeting

Comment: Probably because it's `onclick` as noted multiple times above

Comment: Thats ment to be onclick, I'll revise what of what I tested might have actually worked. Thanks @epascarello

Comment: @epascarello Thanks that was the proplem, my way works

Comment: since you're using `[].forEach`, you could also use `querySelector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take at it : http://jsfiddle.net/cdL51w2g/

```
function avoidHover() {
    var userDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('contentUser');

    for(var i=0; i<userDivs.length; i++){
        userDivs[i].onclick = function(){
            var target = this.getElementsByClassName('contentButtonWrap');
            target[0].style.backgroundColor='green';
        };
    }
};
```

I changed the way to access the children in the parent `div`and used the function `onclick` instead of `click` in the question.

Comment: @Daniel Williams - Thanks a lot. I had a spelling issue(click instead of onclick) My way works, just as yours. Any reason for looping your way over mine?

Answer (score 1):

"onclick" instead of "click". Sorry about that...

```
function avoidHover() {
    var userDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('contentUser');
    [].forEach.call(userDivs, function(e){
        e.onclick = function(){

            var target = e.getElementsByClassName('contentButtonWrap');
            target[0].style.backgroundColor='green';
            };
    });
};
```